# Help deriving third order gaussian optics formula.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, physics

We are given:

1. $$\frac{n_1}{l_0}+\frac{n_2}{l_i}=\frac{1}{R}(\frac{n_2s_i}{l_i}-\frac{n_1s_0}{l_0})$$
2. $$l_0=\sqrt{R^2+(s_0+R)^2-2R(s_0+R)cos(\phi)}$$
3. $$l_i=\sqrt{R^2+(s_i-R)^2+2R(s_i-R)cos(\phi)}$$
4. $$ h= R\;sin(\phi) $$

The equation we want to derive is

$$\frac{n_1}{s_0}+\frac{n_2}{s_i}=\frac{n_2-n_1}{R}+h^2(\frac{n_1}{2s_0}(\frac{1}{s_0}+\frac{1}{R})^2+\frac{n_2}{2s_i}(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{s_i})^2)$$

We are told to proceed by replacing $cos(\phi)$ with its third degree taylor polynomial, and to use the first two terms in the binomial series of $\frac{1}{l_i}$ and $\frac{1}{l_0}$ as well as approximating $\phi$ by $sin(\phi)$.

I can't seem to get this solution even using these hints. 
I am representing $cos(\phi)$ by $1-\frac{\phi^2}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{l_i}$ and $\frac{1}{l_0}$ as $2-l_i$ and $2-l_0$ respectively.

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat Thanks for the link, I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Should $l_i = \sqrt{R^2 + (s_i - R)^2 + 2R(s_i-R) \cos \phi}$ instead of $s_0$?

Comment: @heropup yes, good catch

Comment: Another question:  where did the $h$ come from?  It doesn't appear in any of the three numbered equations, yet it is in the equation you wish to derive.

Comment: @heropup treat h as $Rsin(\phi)$

Comment: It would be helpful if a sketch of rays traced around the lens, focal points, object and image distances.. is attached.

Comment: Replacing  $\frac{1}{l_i}$ and $\frac{1}{l_0}$ as $2-l_i$ and $2-l_0$ is incorrect. Physically any dimension L should not be replaced by 1/L.

Comment: One practical comment: For the purposes of this derivation, you can take the unit of length to be $R$. That effectively sets $R\to 1$ in all equations; it can be restored at the end by rescaling all lengths by $R$ e.g. $l_0\to l_0/R$.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no optics ray diagram and space for comments is inadequate I am commenting as follows in the Answers space with some numerical values which may not be representative of the needed optical configuration:

R = 1.06384/.665179;

h=1.0;n1=1.1;n2=1.5;so =5.8;si=4.7;lo = 5.6;li= 3.2;

lhsEQ

lhs=n1/lo+n2/li

rhsEQ

rhs= (n2 si/li -n1 so/lo)/R

csph=1-(h/R)^2;

lo2=R^2+(so+R)^2-2 R (so+R)csph;li2=R^2+(so-R)^2+2 R (so-R)csph;

LHSEQ

LHS= n1/so + n2/si

aa= (1/so+1/R)^2 n1/(2 so);bb= (1/so-1/R)^2 n2/(2 si) ;

RHSEQ

RHS = (n2-n1)/R + h^2 ( aa +bb )

After execution, results of left and right hand sides tally in the Gaussian formula but not in its linearized version.